# Are some applications of the theorem of Baire?

Tags: general-topology

Good night, someone could help me with some interesting applications of this important theorem and also I could say how I draw a dense subset in the complete space used in the theorem.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The existence of a nowhere differentiable function. If you want to read it take a look at Munkres in chapter 49. It is a really fun excercise to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Baire space, whereas $\mathbb{R\backslash \mathbb{Q}}$ is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the type of result that you're looking for, but you use Baire category to show that a Banach space cannot have a countably-infinite Hamel basis {$e_i$}: the span of a given basis element is nowhere-dense in the Banach space, so that the union of the span of the countably-many $e_i$ is a countable union of nowhere-dense sets, so that it cannot span a complete metric (normed) space--a Banach space.